# Android Studio / IntelliJ Editor Notification Ribbon on HiDPI

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio, phpstorm, webstorm

Is there any way of resizing the editor notification ribbon (shown below) in any IDEA based IDE?

I'm having an issue where using a non-standard OS font magnification ratio (225%) on an UHD display makes these dialogues almost unusable. I wasn't able to find any configuration options for it though, and setting my font size to 200% (the HiDPI equivalent of 100%, the setting most people use I guess) isn't an option because the general font size would be too small.

[image: PHPStorm ribbon size]

Comment: AFAIk there is no such "resizing" options. You could try 200% for OS font .. and then alter font size in actual IDE (it can do both editor and GUI fonts separately) -- *may* work better. But this would affect this app only, of course, which is not good enough for you, as I understand. Other than that I may only suggest to submit a ticket to the Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Thanks, @LazyOne, I just did. I was hoping there was a workaround available.

Comment: Try newer builds -- should be fixed (if I understood it correctly -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-137398 -- `builds 142.152, 141.873`) -- todays PhpStorm v9 EAP build should have it.

Comment: You're right, it is fixed in the latest EAP for PhpStorm (just updated and checked). Waiting for the next AS release to clear my UI of HiDPI issues :) Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, @LazyOne. Feel free to copy your comment in an answer and I'll accept it.